# Parse can't add data to object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add data to array on self hosted parse.

this is my code.

```
notification.addUniqueObjects(from: [currentUser], forKey: "readMembers")
notification.saveEventually()
```

and I'm getting this error

```
Warning: `BFTask` caught an exception in the continuation block. This behavior is discouraged and will be removed in a future release. Caught Exception: Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)
```

Comment: Can you post the set up for your `notification`?

Comment: let notification = self.notifications[indexPath.row]

also it is only pfobject I just fetched it from table.
@AlekPiasecki

Comment: Is it possible your `from: [currentUser]` is incorrect? Did you set it as, for example, `let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?`?

Comment: I am using swift 3 so I just used             
'let currentUser = PFUser.current()'

Comment: also it's still not working @AlekPiasecki

Comment: Try `let currentUser = PFUser.current().objectId` and store this in the array, parse array accepts only strings and not objects...

Comment: I tried it too. Actuall it can store pfobjects and pfusers in array but now Its giving me this error @MazelTov